# Implementing XML encryption using pycrypto to parse LCP-encoded file

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto, drm

I'm trying to implement the [LCP DRM](https://readium.org/lcp-specs/releases/lcp/latest) in Python and I'm having trouble understanding the data flow in their initial encryption process.

The key section of their `license.lcpl` file is

```
{                                                                                                    
    "provider":"http://www.epagine.fr",                                                              
    "id":"6666065a-e7bd-44b4-93ad-abd0336374dd",                                                     
    "issued":"....",                                                                 
    "encryption":                                                                                    
    {                                                                                                
        "profile":"http://readium.org/lcp/profile-1.0",                                              
        "content_key":{                                                                              
            "algorithm":"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc",                               
            "encrypted_value":"itxQlsi5sxcSZ89eW2m80UCOyEDqBZzgTX3E/kG3rqWstvnFXOqOXVwiodlHUmtUSqxdbToy02fubOSt1/37AQ=="
        },                                                                                           
        "user_key":{                                                                                 
            "algorithm":"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256",                                   
            "text_hint":"Quelle est votre Clé LCP ?",
 "key_check":"pFoXDupsQReQ5H5e9Vg6JtHkjkbVkOlkGYUWvWmFSgfZN8anAyMP7T6+zW3FJn+GzQpatvRQW7W54wixrUeorQ=="}

    },
```

This means - I believe - that the `User Passphrase` `4EeffRhPz6` (or could this be the 256-bit `User Key`?) issued by the vendor should hash to *some* `User Key` value H of length 256 bits. Then I should be able to extract the AES initialization vector from the data in the `key_check` field, and use AES256-CBC to encrypt the `id` `6666065a-e7bd-44b4-93ad-abd0336374dd` to the value of `key_check`. Having done that, I should use the inverse procedure to decrypt the content key and then use the content keys to decrypt my files. (Data from an example file is given at bottom.)

I believe the relevant value of H is `VDDcCeWkbZlZnjc5yJ+L0YDJqgvF480ej2cnqw3qMhE=` and the IV should be `pFoXDupsQReQ5H5e9Vg6Jg==`. But I'm not sure and I can't replicate the `key_check` field. I've been working with the `pycrypto` library and converting everything to bytes before passing them as arguments.

Some of my work:

```
In [142]: from Crypto.Hash import SHA256, AES
In [143]: h = SHA256.new()
In [144]: h.update(b'4EeffRhPz6')
In [146]: h.digest()
Out[146]: b"T0\xdc\t\xe5\xa4m\x99Y\x9e79\xc8\x9f\x8b\xd1\x80\xc9\xaa\x0b\xc5\xe3\xcd\x1e\x8fg'\xab\r\xea2\x11"

In [147]: codecs.encode(h.digest(),'base64')
Out[147]: b'VDDcCeWkbZlZnjc5yJ+L0YDJqgvF480ej2cnqw3qMhE=\n'

In [148]: ciphertext = codecs.decode(b'itxQlsi5sxcSZ89eW2m80UCOyEDqBZzgTX3E/kG3rqWstvnFXOqOXVwiodlHUmtUSqxdbToy02fubOSt1/37AQ==','base64')
In [149]: key_check = codecs.decode(b"pFoXDupsQReQ5H5e9Vg6JtHkjkbVkOlkGYUWvWmFSgfZN8anAyMP7T6+zW3FJn+GzQpatvRQW7W54wixrUeorQ==",'base64')
In [150]: iv = key_check[:16]
In [151]: user_key_bytes = h.digest()
In [152]: aes_obj = AES.new(user_key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

In [153]: codecs.encode(aes_obj.encrypt(id_field.replace('-','')),'base64')
Out[153]: b'uTP9Z7ykqxS5xnpwafgxE12KBd5HuHdPARE2Qa64OsI=\n'

In [154]: codecs.encode(iv + aes_obj.encrypt(id_field.replace('-','')),'base64')
Out[154]: b'pFoXDupsQReQ5H5e9Vg6Jifk96zVYc4Ast38IQfR6z6sMqUxrTTbNEwQVJRxT2S6\n' # wrong
```

Contents of `c01_cover.xhtml`, which has been shrunk using `Deflate` before encryption and has 792 bytes originally:

`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`

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: There may be something relevant to key padding in here: https://github.com/readium/readium-lcp-server/issues/18

Comment: The specification link you posted seems to only apply to the "basic" profile, not to the "profile-1.0" that your eBook uses - see https://readium.org/lcp-specs/registries/profiles for details. Looks like they don't publish information about the profile-1.0 format so people can't crack the DRM.

Comment: You're right. I emailed them and they explained it!